# Show that $I_n=\int_0^1{(1-x^2)^n\,dx}$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$I_n=\int_0^1{(1-x^2)^n\,dx}\,\,\,\,\,\,\, n\in\mathbb N^* $$
I still have trouble proving convergence of series. I am still working on it though. Here is what I have tried and please correct me if I am wrong.

To prove a series is convergent I need to prove that it is monotone and bounded.

I calculated $I_{n+1}-I_n$ and it is $\le 0$ which means the series is decreasing.

Now I need to prove it is bounded. That is the same thing as proving $\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n$ exists and is not equal to $\infty$ or $-\infty$, right?

I tried to find the limit but here is where I always have problems. Experience (granted very limited) taught me that most of the times we can use Squeeze Theorem to find the limit with this kind of exercises so this is what I try next.

Normally I would use the given fact that $0 \le x \le 1$ and try to rewrite this double inequality until I am getting a double inequality involving $I_n$ and then take the limit of left and right side and hope they're the same. I rarely have success with this so I think it's not a good idea. What would be a good idea instead?

I know this might seem very basic to you and I hope I will feel the same things it soon, with your help.

Comment: You're terminology is slightly confusing. The term "series" is usually used for sequences that arise through summation of other sequences. You seem to be using it as a synonym for "sequence" without any summation implied.

Comment: English is not my main language, the word for word translation to English is that of series of integrals.

Comment: It's bounded below by zero. Can you see why?

Comment: You can tell exactly what the limit is.  Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-x^2)^n=0$ for $0<x\le 1$, you can show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n=0$ using theorems like dominated convergence thm, or uniform convergence on compact intervals.  Or you can directly compute $$I_n=\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}=\frac{2n\cdot(2n-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot 2}{(2n+1)\cdot (2n-1)\cdot \ldots \cdot 3}.$$

Answer (score 4):

You’re overthinking this. You’ve already proved that the sequence is monotonically decreasing. To prove that it’s bounded from below, you merely have to observe that the integrand is non-negative, and thus so is the integral.